# Automated email cakephp 3.x

Tags: email, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to develop a system which allows the user to enter a date and time. Then at entered time the system send an email to the user. I already have the system. All I am looking for is a way to send emails at a given time. I can send emails but cannot programme them to be sent on a precise date and time. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be solves by using a "cron job" that checks at some interval whether there's any emails to be send now.

You could simply make a single Cake Shell (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html) and use some built-in task runner (eg. cron on linux) - but you could also use a plugin for this principle and have that part set up for you.

For a quick'n'easy plugin that works for lots of sites: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue.

The functionality you're asking is even built into this plugin already! :)

You'll have got create a class like this: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue/blob/master/src/Shell/Task/QueueExampleTask.php#L74 and then just create a new job of this task and set the `notbefore` parameter to the time you want this email to be sent.

Check the readme here: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue/tree/master/docs.

Remark: The email will be sent when the worker executes the given task, so it will be x time *after* the `notbefore` property, depending on your amount of workers and jobs - and how long time they'll take to execute.